# Symfony 3 - in prod, assetic works fine with "AppKernel('prod', true)", not with "AppKernel('prod', false)"

Tags: symfony

in prod mode, everything is working with this configuration (app.php):

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

When i turn "$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);" to false, the display does not work fully.

This is my config.yml (for assetic):

```
# ASSETIC BUNDLE
assetic:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

I always do this:

```
- pbc cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
- pbc assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

(alias pbc for php bin/console)

If I inspect the code, i can see all .css are not dump:

```
<head>
        ....
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/app.css">            
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/user.css">
        ....
</head>
```

Because when AppKernel is set to true, i can see that:

```
<head>
        .....
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/app_bootstrap.min_1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/app_dataTables.bootstrap.min_2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/app_font-awesome_3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/app_custom_front_4.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/app_header_5.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/app_footer_6.css">      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/user_user_1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/compiled/user_select2.min_2.css">
        .....
</head>
```

I know that i can't set AppKernel to true in prod mode, so it's very important to fix this problem. I read a lot of topic but i don't find the solution...

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

deleted cache directories in

> /home/[user]/www/[site]/var/cache

and it works fine

the problem occured when migrated to another server